# I can't open Carrot2 Workbench on WIndows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10, compatibility, carrot2

I tried to open Carrot2 Workbench in my Windows 10 x64 with JRE 9.0.4 but there is an error like this:

```
!SESSION 2018-02-26 22:49:13.739 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=9.0.4
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-02-26 22:49:17.110
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.carrot2.workbench.core (45).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.carrot2.workbench.core.WorkbenchCorePlugin.start() of bundle org.carrot2.workbench.core.
```

full log: https://en.pastebin.ca/3977647

Please any kind of help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Looks like it might be the common Java 9 problem. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrot2 Workbench currently does not support Java 9. To make it work, use Java 8 for now.